# Verificacion de DNI en python

Tags: python, funciones

Necesito verificar con una función que el dni introducido es válido, si tiene entre 7 y 8 dígitos devuelve true y si no false. sin embargo, tengo un problema.

```
cedula=int(input("introduce tu numero de cedula: ")) #inserta cedula
cedula1=str(cedula) #se convierte el numero en string
# print(cedula1)
numeroCedula=[] #creamos lista

 for digito in cedula1:   #para cada digito de cedula1 entonces agregalo a la lista
numeroCedula.append(digito)
```

en esta parte de arriba también inserta el numero completo a la lista no sé por que

```
 def verifCedula(numeroCedula):
      if len(numeroCedula) >= 7 or len(numeroCedula) <= 8:
         print(f'la cedula:{cedula} es valida')
         return 'true'
      else:
          print(f'la cedula: {cedula} no es valida')
     return 'false'

  verifCedula(numeroCedula)
```

y en la función al parecer no está verificando la longitud de la lista.

Comment: `numeroCedula=list(input("introduce tu numero de cedula: ")) ` lo resuelve de una patada, sin tantas vueltas.

Comment: A titulo informativo, este tipo de datos no suele tratarse como numerico, ya que son numeros, pero en realidad no lo son... o sea, no lo transformes a numero...

Comment: ok, entonces solo quitaria el int del input para ahorrarme la transformacion del mismo a string. ahora mi duda es que cuando hago esto                        
           for digito in cedula1:   
              numeroCedula.append(digito)                                                                                   me a;ade tambien el numero completo del dni a la lista, por que pasa esto? y como lo corregiria, si por ejemplo el dni es 1234567 anade uno por uno por separado y tambien anade 1234567 @gbianchi

Comment: ok muchas gracias @CandidMoe

Answer (score 1):

Con esta función puedes verificar si un DNI, un NIE o un CIF de empresa es válido.

La función comprueba que el NIF indicado tenga 9 dígitos y también valida los digitos control para verificar si el DNI, NIE o CIF introducido es válido.

Retorna un valor True o False según sea válido o no.

```
def validarNIF(NIF: str):

validacionNIF: bool = True
esDNI: bool = False
esNIE: bool = False
esCIF: bool = False

patronDNI: str = "[0-9]{8}[A-Z]"
patronNIE: str = "[X-Z][0-9]{7}[A-Z]"
patronCIF: str = "[A-H|K-N|P-S|U-W][0-9]{8}"

tamano: int = NIF.__len__()

if(tamano > 9):

    validacionNIF = False

DNIValido: Match = re.match(patronDNI, NIF)

if(DNIValido != None):

    esDNI = True

NIEValido: Match = re.match(patronNIE, NIF)

if(NIEValido != None):

    esNIE = True

CIFValido: Match = re.match(patronCIF, NIF)

if(CIFValido != None):

    esCIF = True

if(esDNI):

    digitosControl: str = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE"
    DNIInvalidos: list = ["00000000T", "00000001R", "99999999R"]

    for DNIInvalido in DNIInvalidos:

        if (NIF == DNIInvalido):

            validacionNIF = False

    numerosDNI: int = int(NIF[0:8])

    ultimoDigito: str = NIF[8]

    valorDigitoControl: int = numerosDNI % 23

    if(ultimoDigito != digitosControl[valorDigitoControl]):

        validacionNIF = False

if(esNIE):

    digitosControl: str = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE"

    numerosNIE: int = int(NIF[1:8])

    primerDigito: str = NIF[0]

    ultimoDigito: str = NIF[8]

    if(primerDigito == "X"):

        valorDigitoControl: int = numerosNIE % 23

        if(ultimoDigito != digitosControl[valorDigitoControl]):

            validacionNIF = False

    if(primerDigito == "Y"):

        valorDigitoControl: int = (10000000 + numerosNIE) % 23

        if(ultimoDigito != digitosControl[valorDigitoControl]):

            validacionNIF = False

    if(primerDigito == "Z"):

        valorDigitoControl: int = (20000000 + numerosNIE) % 23

        if(ultimoDigito != digitosControl[valorDigitoControl]):

            validacionNIF = False

if(esCIF):

    contador: int = 2

    sumaNumerosPares: int = 0
    sumaNumerosImpares: int = 0

    while(contador <= 8):

        numeroImpar: int = int(NIF[contador - 1])

        if(contador != 8):

            sumaNumerosPares += int(NIF[contador])

            dobleNumeroImpar: int = numeroImpar * 2

            if(dobleNumeroImpar > 10):

                numeroImpar = (dobleNumeroImpar % 10) + 1

            sumaNumerosImpares += numeroImpar

        else:

            dobleNumeroImpar: int = numeroImpar * 2

            if (dobleNumeroImpar > 10):

                numeroImpar = (dobleNumeroImpar % 10) + 1

            sumaNumerosImpares += numeroImpar

        contador += 2

    sumaTotal: int = sumaNumerosPares + sumaNumerosImpares

    digitoControl: int = 10 - (sumaTotal % 10)

    letraControl = chr(64 + digitoControl)

    primerDigito: str = NIF[0]

    if(primerDigito == "A" or primerDigito == "B" or primerDigito == "E" or primerDigito == "H"):

        ultimoDigito: int = int(NIF[8])

        if(ultimoDigito != digitoControl):

            validacionNIF = False

    if(primerDigito == "K" or primerDigito == "P" or primerDigito == "Q" or primerDigito == "S"):

        ultimoDigito: str = NIF[8]

        if(ultimoDigito != letraControl):

            validacionNIF = False

if(esDNI == False and esNIE == False and esCIF == False):

    validacionNIF = False

return validacionNIF
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que la función retorne un booleano `True` si pasa la verificación o `False` en caso contrario. La función no debe imprimir cosas, a menos que sea explicitamente una función de ese tipo, o bien para notificar al desarrollador errores o debug.

```
def verifCedula(numeroCedula):
    if numeroCedula.isdigit() and len(numeroCedula) in [7, 8]:
        # Si la cadena esta compuesta de numeros y mide 7 o 8 caracteres
        return True
    return False
```

Ahora el programa principal es quien maneja la lógica:

```
cedula = input("Introduce el numero de cedula: ")
if verifCedula(cedula):
    print(f'La cedula {cedula} es valida')
    cedList = list(cedula) # <-- Cedula en lista (si asi la requieres)
    # ...
    # Código, o llamadas a otras funcionas, para procesar la cedula
else:
    print(f'La cedula {cedula} NO es valida')
```

`cedList` tendrá una lista de caracteres enteros `['3', '8', ...]`. Como seguramente esa lista la vas a recorrer en algún ciclo posterior, le puedes aplicar `int()` a cada elemento con total seguridad; pero si la querías que desde ya fuera entera, entonces puedes reemplazar:

```
cedList = list(cedula)
```

por

```
cedList = list(int(x) for x in cedula)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal está en cómo estás realizando la verificación de la longitud de la lista numeroCedula en la función verifCedula(). La condición if len(numeroCedula) >= 7 or len(numeroCedula) <= 8: siempre será verdadera porque estás usando un operador or en lugar de and. Además, deberías estar verificando si la longitud está dentro del rango deseado, no solo mayor o igual a 7 o menor o igual a 8.

Aquí te dejo el código corregido:

```
cedula = int(input("introduce tu numero de cedula: "))
cedula1 = str(cedula)
numeroCedula = []
for digito in cedula1:
    numeroCedula.append(digito)

def verifCedula(numeroCedula):
    if 7 <= len(numeroCedula) <= 8:
        print(f'la cedula: {"".join(numeroCedula)} es valida')
        return True
    else:
        print(f'la cedula: {"".join(numeroCedula)} no es valida')
        return False
verifCedula(numeroCedula)
```